# function for contact form 7 registration form

Tags: php, function, contact-form-7

I am trying to modify a function for WordPress Contact Form 7 user registration from working for one form to multiple forms.

I tried modifying code someone shared online but I am not good enough using php BUT learning! Thank you in advance for some advice.

```
//  create Registration

function create_user_from_registration($cfdata) {
    if (!isset($cfdata->posted_data) && class_exists('WPCF7_Submission')) {
        // Contact Form 7 version 3.9 removed $cfdata->posted_data and now
        // we have to retrieve it from an API
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ($submission) {
            $formdata = $submission->get_posted_data();
        }
    } elseif (isset($cfdata->posted_data)) {
        // For pre-3.9 versions of Contact Form 7
        $formdata = $cfdata->posted_data;
    } else {
        // We can't retrieve the form data
        return $cfdata;
    }
    // Check this is the user registration form by checking the title
    if ( $cfdata->title() == 'Registration: Retailer') {
        $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
        $email = $formdata['email'];
        $name = $formdata['username'];
        // Construct a username from the user's name
        $username = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $name));
        $name_parts = explode(' ',$name);
        if ( !email_exists( $email ) ) {
            // Find an unused username
            $username_tocheck = $username;
            $i = 1;
            while ( username_exists( $username_tocheck ) ) {
                $username_tocheck = $username . $i++;
            }
            $username = $username_tocheck;
            // Create the user
            $userdata = array(
                'user_login' => $username,
                'user_pass' => $password,
                'user_email' => $email,
                'nickname' => reset($name_parts),
                'display_name' => $formdata['company'],
                'first_name' => $formdata['firstname'],
                'last_name' => $formdata['lastname'],
                'role' => 'customer'
            );
            $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
            if ( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
                // Email login details to user
                $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
                $message = "Hello! We have received your registration, Your login details are as follows:" . "\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $username) . "\r\n";
                $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $password) . "\r\n";
                $message .= home_url() . "\r\n";
                wp_mail($email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), $blogname), $message);
            }
        }
    }
    return $cfdata;
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'create_user_from_registration', 1);
```

the above code will register the user to the website but it only works for one form. I have 3 forms I would like to apply this to. Perhaps elseif for looking at the title. I am too new at this and want to learn.

Comment: If you simply want to execute the code inside the if for multiple forms, then this doesn’t need any else/elseif (those would be for when you want to do _different_ things for different forms.) You can use `in_array` to check if the form name is one of multiple given values.

Comment: OK, that makes sense; thank you so much for your advice. I researched in_array in the php manual and in examples. I am just not getting it right. Here is what I tried:

```
if (in_array ( $cfdata->title() == 'Registration1', 'Registration1', 'Registration1') ) 
```
and

```
if (in_array ( $cfdata->title() == 'Registration1', $cfdata->title() == 'Registration2', $cfdata->title() == 'Registration3') )
```

I cannot figure out the proper way to write this.

Comment: The `==` comparisons don’t belong in there. `in_array('foo', ['foo', 'bar'])` is how you use it - first parameter the single value, second parameter the array you want to check it for.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I was able to make it work. Thanks so much! - so very grateful.